# How to get Default Back button item Event..?

Tags: iphone

How to get Default back button Event in navigation application.. how to write a code on click of back button item (note:without viewWillDisappear and also not create Left bar button item) it's possible..??

Answer (score 0):

Use the custom navigation back button to capture the touches.

```
UIButton *myButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];   
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"goback.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];   
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];  
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem= [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton ] autorelease];
```

And implement the `backButtonClicked:` method in your controller.

```
-(void) backButtonClicked:(id) sender
{
    UIBarButtonItem * myButton = (UIBarButtonItem *) sender;
}
```

Comment: you forget to put autorelease in this [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton] autorelease];

Comment: welcome. Do you know anything about jailbroken apps development? If yes I need to create a sms sending and receiving app. Could you please help me regarding this? Thanks

Comment: @dipen chudasama : could you show in code how you are doing ?

Comment: @dipen chudasama : then use `backBarButtonItem` instead `leftBarButtonItem` ...  check updated answer ..

Comment: @Jhaliya I need your help... can you provide me your mail address?

Comment: @Jhaliya my mail id is rahul.vyas.09@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol for the back view.